# How an independent object can call method from the caller class?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I have an independent class with template that does overloading for some operator and I want to put it as a trigger for the caller class.
Example code:

> Independent Class

```
template <typename DataType>
class IndependentClass{
public:
   DataType _value; 
   IndependentClass(){};
   IndependentClass(DataType val):_value(val){};
   ~IndependentClass(){};
   IndependentClass& operator=(const IndependentClass<DataType>& mu){
      if (this != &mu){
         _value = mu._value;
         //I want to trigger caller method from here
         //But how this class can know the caller class?
         // _caller.callParentMethod();
      }
      return (*this);
   }
   IndependentClass& operator=(int val){
      return (operator=(IndependentClass<DataType>(val)));
   }
   DataType getValue()const{
      return _value;
   }
};
```

> Base Class

```
class BaseClass{
public:
   int sum;
   BaseClass(){};
   ~BaseClass(){};
   void setValue(int value){sum+=value;}
   int getValue(){return sum;}
};
```

> Derived Class

The Independent class will be used in this class.

```
//Declare Independent Class
typedef IndependentClass<int> I8;
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
public:
   I8 sumThisClassValue;
   DerivedClass(){
      methodDerivedClass();
   };
   ~DerivedClass(){};
   void methodDerivedClass(){
      sumThisClassValue = 8;
      Base::setValue(4);
      cout<<"Value = "<<Base::getValue()<<endl; //Output 4
      cout<<sumThisClassValue<<endl;
      cout<<"Value = "<<Base::getValue()<<endl; //Output that I want is 12
   }
   void callParentMethod(int _val){
      Base::setValue(_val);
   }
};
```

> Main

```
int main(){
   DerivedClass objectTLM;
   return 0;
}
```

So far I was thinking to use 2 template `template<typename DataType, typename Caller>` and add another constructor in my Independent Class, but still how can I pass the derived Class itself i.e `(I8 objA = new I8(this))` *It did not work either

In the real code scenario, I have multiple derived class from the same base class, and the base class can monitor each value for each derived class.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It look like some type of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). but I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: Seems like you should use composition instead of inheritance and also think about your design, this doesn't make much sense, `getValue` works on `sum`, not `sumThisClassValue`.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the code little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndependentClass` needs to have a reference to an instance of `DerivedClass` to call `callParentMethod` on it. You can't change the parameters of `operator =`, so it will have to be a member of `IndependentClass`.

```
class DerivedClass;

template <typename DataType>
class IndependentClass{
   DerivedClass & _caller;
public:
   DataType _value; 
   IndependentClass(DerivedClass & caller, DataType val = {}) : _caller(caller), _value(val) {};
   IndependentClass(const IndependentClass &) = delete;
   IndependentClass& operator= (const IndependentClass &) = delete;
   IndependentClass& operator= (int mu) {
      _value = mu;
      _caller.callParentMethod();
      return *this;
   }

   DataType getValue() const {
      return _value;
   }
};

using I8 = IndependentClass<int>;
```

Note that if you do that, you still won't get the output that you are asking for, because you will be adding 8 to the uninitialised `BaseClass::sum` value before adding 4 to it.

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
public:
   I8 sumThisClassValue;

   DerivedClass() : sumThisClassValue(*this) {
      methodDerivedClass();
   };

   void methodDerivedClass(){
      Base::setValue(4);
      std::cout << "Value = " << Base::getValue() << std::endl; //Output 4
      sumThisClassValue = 8;
      std::cout << sumThisClassValue._value << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Value = " << Base::getValue() << std::endl; //Output 12
   }

   void callParentMethod(int _val){
      Base::setValue(_val);
   }
};
```